# Catching multiple exceptions with Unit Method

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I am trying to write a JUnit for my `suchAutor()` method.
The Problem is that I throw two different Exception and I only know how to handle tests that throw one exception.

```
public Buch[] suchAutor(String gesuchterName) throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException {
    if (gesuchterName == "") {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bitte geben sie einen Nachnamen ein.");
    }
    Buch[] erg = new Buch[0];
    int arraylength = 0;
    Boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < buecher.length; i++) {
        for (int u = 0; u < buecher[i].getAutoren().length; u++) {
            if (buecher[i].getAutoren()[u].getNachname() == gesuchterName) {
                found = true;
                arraylength++;
                erg = Arrays.copyOf(erg, arraylength);
                erg[arraylength - 1] = buecher[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(erg));
        return erg;
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Zu dem gesuchten Autor wurden keine Bücher gefunden.");
    }
}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert() {
    try {
        bibliothek.suchAutor("");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now the test fails because an empty String just throws an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: You should write individual unit tests for each exceptions hat your method could throw.  The method can only throw one exception at a time.

Comment: but when I do I get an error for the IlegelArgument Exception: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: I also wouldn't bother writing a try-catch block in the test - just add the relevant `throws` clause to the method signature

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just pressed on quick fix and this works now :D

```
    @Test
    public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert() {
        try {
            bibliothek.suchAutor("");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This also works if suchAutor() does NOT throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

The question is tagged with junit5, and Jupiter has specially dedicated [assertThrows](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions) facility:

```java
 @Test
 void failsOnEmptyName(){
     assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, ()-> bibliothek.suchAutor(""));
 }
```

Comment: Totally missed the JUnit5 tag, I just looked at the test style an assumed JUnit4.  My bad.

Comment: Even sitting under Jupiter's root many people prefer to stick with habitual junit4 design. So it's better to be aware of both approaches :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Junit4:

```
public class MyTest {
   @Rule
   public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

   @Test 
   public void myTest() throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException {
      thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
      myObject.suchAutor("");
   }

   @Test 
   public void myOtherTest() throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException {
      thrown.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
      myObject.suchAutor("An Unknown Autor");
   }
}
```

In the above we use a rule to same that the following code should throw and exception, if the test doesn't throw and exception or throws an exception other than `IllegalArgumentException` then the test will fail.

We set the rule up so that by default it expects no exception, any test not testing for exceptions should work correctly.

see [JUnit Docs](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html)

Comment: I tried it this way now:

 @Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert() {
  try {
   bibliothek.suchAutor("");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

  } 
 }
 
 @Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert2() {
  try {
   bibliothek.suchAutor("");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

  } 
 }

But no it says: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format the comment code :(

Comment: use single back quotes around the bits of code.  No apologies needed we are all learning :)

Comment: `@Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert() {
  try {
   bibliothek.suchAutor("");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

  } 
 }
 
 @Test(expected = Exception.class)
 public void testSuchAutorGrenzwert2() {
  try {
   bibliothek.suchAutor("");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

  } 
 }`

Comment: The error is because you have told the Test annotation (`@Test`) to expect `Exception` but it actually getting `FileNotFoundException` if you change the expectation to be `FileNotFoundException.class` I suspect your test will pass

Comment: I changed that now, but the error isn't in that test function. I have the error in the `bibliothek.suchAutor("");`line from the IllegalArgumentException function.

Comment: "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException"

Comment: This is because I forgot to add the throws clauses to my test methods as @JonK pointed out.

Comment: there was a quick fix suggestion the whole time... just saw it. It works now the way I posted. But thanks a lot @Gavin ! :)